# msSaveOrOpenBlob property doesn't exist on type Navigator angular 13

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript, angular13

The property msSaveOrOpenBlob doesn't exist on type Navigator after updating to the angular 13.

I know the `Navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob` is being deprecated as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/msSaveOrOpenBlob#browser_compatibility

I had an angular 12 application, now I am migrating to angular 13 and typescript have been updated to the latest version, but facing the issue of `The property msSaveOrOpenBlob doesn't exist on type Navigator`

what will be the alternate code for the below

```
if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
            navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
        }
```

Comment: Angular 13 does not support Internet Explorer. Why don't you just drop the code? Even if you compile it, the condition will never be true

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina I was using this for Edge at one point. I think Edge changed to Chromium at some point; would that have made this useless also for Edge?

Answer (score 4):

```
let newVariable: any = window.navigator;
var newBlob = new Blob([res.body], { type: "application/csv" });
if (newVariable && newVariable.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    newVariable.msSaveOrOpenBlob(newBlob);
    return;
}
```

Comment: I didn't test it, but I suppose that TypeScript infers the type, so nothing changes. Maybe would be correct doing `window.navigator as unknown as any`, but as I said in my comment the whole snippet is just useless

Answer (score 2):

Found some of the references

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator/issues/1029
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45612

Use the declaration merging and declare the types locally in your project work.

Answer (score 0):

Declare below code in main.ts

```
  declare global{
    interface Navigator {
      msSaveOrOpenBlob?: (blob: any, defaultName?: string) => boolean
    }
  }
```